# GUI библиотеки для Планкалкюль

Tags: gui, библиотеки

Подскажите GUI библиотеки для Планкалкюль, или подобные Qt.

Comment: А вообще кто-нибудь есть пишущий на таком раритете?

Comment: Ого, я думал, об этом языке пишут только в исторических обзорах.

Comment: По сути что-то типа этого и есть. Собираем информацию.